# Characterization of left invertible functors

Tags: category-theory

What are the split monomorphisms in $\mathbf{Cat}$, forgetting 2-categorical structure?

So far I know that they are faithful and injective on objects, since those functors are the monomorphisms in $\mathbf{Cat}$. The context in which this question came up makes me guess that fullness might play a role or that the image is closed under taking isomorphism classes. I have no idea how to prove that though.

Comment: No, there's no fullness as any split group mono is a split category mono, and there's no repleteness of the image as every functor including the terminal category as an object is split. I'm generally skeptical that these are easy to characterize-semidirect products of groups are already substantial theory and I doubt they generalize to monoids, let alone categories. You may have been reading about monomorphic functors which are split *by their right or left adjoint*, which are much more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything interesting to say about this condition; it doesn't strike me as very natural, among other things because it ignores natural transformations.

The natural condition, as Kevin Carlson says, is a functor being split by an adjoint. Formally, if $F : C \to D$ is a left adjoint and $G : D \to C$ is its right adjoint, we have unit and counit natural transformations

$$\varepsilon : \text{id}_C \to GF$$
$$\eta : FG \to \text{id}_D$$

and it's an interesting and natural question to ask what happens if either of these is an isomorphism. It turns out (this is a straightforward exercise) that the unit $\varepsilon$ is an isomorphism iff $F$ is fully faithful and the counit $\eta$ is an isomorphism iff $G$ is fully faithful.

Related and also quite interesting is the notion of an [idempotent adjunction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/idempotent+adjunction).